# Spring boot does not run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, mvn-repo

Spring boot does not run

I have configured this version of spring boot in pom.xml:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> <version>2.7.16</version>
```

If I execute `mvn clean install`, it finish successul (it generates the build), but when I try to run the app with spring boot:

`mvn spring-boot:run`
or
`mvn spring-boot:run -D"spring-boot.run.profiles"=local`
or
`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=LOCAL -Xdebug -  DprocessorIntegrationTest.debug=true"`

It does not work, this is the trace of error:

```
[INFO\] BUILD FAILURE [INFO\] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO\] Total time:  41.962 s [INFO\] Finished at: 2023-10-31T19:08:38+01:00 [INFO\] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR\] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.16:run (default-cli) on project: Application finished with exit code: 1 -\> \[Help 1\] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.16:run (default-cli) on project - Application finished with exit code: 1 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1 at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:103) at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:291) at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:255) at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:225) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) `
```

Could you kindly help me?

Regards.

Comment: Is this your complete stacktrace? there seems to be a build issue with your project.

Comment: If you have finished it via `mvn clean install` try to start the application via `java -jar target/name.jar` and see what happens..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your application.properties file if you have any typos?